# Create a canvas element in angularjs custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

What is the angular way of creating a canvas element in AngularJS custom directive.

> document.createElement('canvas')      **Not Angular Way** 
>   $document.createElement('canvas')  **Error $document.createElement('canvas') is not a function** 
>   angular.element('canvas') **Error related jqLite**

Answer (score 1):

Create element in plain javascript and make it angular. `angular.element` is to use JQLite methods on element in it but not to create element

```
var canvas = angular.element(document.createElement('canvas'));
```

to see the element created by above line, just log the `canvas`

```
console.log(a);
console.log(a[0]);
```

And above element creation line creates only opening tag until it contains a child. So, try to append child to get closing tag

Comment: Can I use $document instead of document. eslint won't allow this.

Comment: You can't use $document because it contains only JQLite collection. For more info https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2630-accessing-document-properties-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: You see here also http://www.techstrikers.com/AngularJS/angularjs-$document-service.php

Comment: $document contains only jQuery collection (or jQLite collection) that contains the document object and its properties.